# R package for multinomial naive Bayes text classification?

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, naive-bayes

I am looking for a multinomial naive Bayes text classification package in R that accepts a term document matrix (from tm) as input for training and classifies new text based on that. I have about 50.000 short documents, which will belong to around 30 different topics (topics are assigned by LDA) and I would like to get a probability score for new documents.

Comment: You have 30 classes? It seems people do multiclass with OAA (one-against-all) Bernoulli naive-Bayes instead of multinomial.